# What is 'EX-101 exhibits'?

Tags: sec

I am studying SEC filings and downloaded the Financial Statement and Notes Data Sets from https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/financial-statement-and-notes-data-set.html.

From readme.htm of the zip files downloaded, it says 'The following data sets provide information extracted from EX-101 exhibits submitted to the Commission in a flattened data format to assist users in more easily consuming the data for analysis.'

I am new to SEC filings and have difficulty reading them. Could anyone please explain what 'EX-101 exhibits' is to me?

Comment: It'd Edgar-speak: https://www.sec.gov/info/edgar/edgartaxonomies.shtml

Comment: @DimitriVulis Thank you very much for letting me know the link!